# discord.py checking permissions within code

Tags: python, discord.py

I've tried this but it didn't work(i marked the error line), I hope you can help me

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'https://' in message.content.lower():
        if(message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")):
            print("")
        else:
  >>>>>>if(has_permissions(manage_messages = True))
            print("")
        else:
            await message.delete()
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Message Deleted',description=f'**User** : ``{str(message.author)}``\n**Reason** : ``Url/Link detected in the Message``', color=0xFF0000 )
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What is the error, can you provide more information about your code? And your code has several syntax problems. At first, you should look how to code in Python.

Comment: Sure the error is in the line with >>>>>> wait i can send you the error

Comment: File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\Bots\ClipoxMain\main.py", line 39
    if(has_permissions(manage_messages = True))
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 2):

You have an indentation error (you must add one indent after your first `else`):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'https://' in message.content.lower():
        if(message.channel.name.startswith("ticket")):
            print("")
        else:
            if(has_permissions(manage_messages = True))
                print("")
            else:
                await message.delete()
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Message Deleted',description=f'**User** : ``{str(message.author)}``\n**Reason** : ``Url/Link detected in the Message``', color=0xFF0000 )
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

To check for permissions withing your code, you can use [`Member.guild_permissions`](http://%5B%60Member.guild_permissions%60%5D%5B1%5D):

```py
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
    print('You have permission')
```